# Timeout expired. - Using Db in ServiceStack Service

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using the `Db` property in a ServiceStack service to access my database but every now and then I get the following error from IIS:

`Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.`

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +6371713
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6372046
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnection.Open() +44
   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection() +132
   ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service.get_Db() +68
```

I have set the `ReuseScope` in the `Configure` method to `ReuseScope.None` which should close the connection on a per request basis I believe? What am I doing wrong here?

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    //Register all your dependencies
    ConfigureDb(container);

    //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
}
```

ConfigureDb:

```
private static void ConfigureDb(Container container)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider))
        .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

    using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
    {
      // Do database seed/initialisation
    }
}
```

### Edit

After more diagnosis, it seems to happen when I refresh the page several times when I call this service method:

```
public Warranty Get(Warranty request)
    {
        var warranty = new Warranty();
        if (request.Id != default(int))
        {
            warranty = Db.Id<Warranty>(request.Id);
            warranty.WarrantyOrder = ResolveService<WarrantyOrderService>().Get(new WarrantyOrder { WarrantyId = warranty.Id });
            warranty.WarrantyStatus = ResolveService<WarrantyStatusService>().Get(new WarrantyStatus { Id = warranty.StatusId });
            warranty.WarrantyNotes = ResolveService<WarrantyNoteService>().Get(new WarrantyNotes { WarrantyId = warranty.Id });
            warranty.WarrantyDialogues = ResolveService<WarrantyDialogueService>().Get(new WarrantyDialogues { WarrantyId = warranty.Id });
            warranty.WarrantyCredit = ResolveService<WarrantyCreditService>().Get(new WarrantyCredit { WarrantyId = warranty.Id });
            warranty.WarrantyPhotos = ResolveService<WarrantyPhotoService>().Get(new WarrantyPhotos { WarrantyReference = warranty.WarrantyReference });
            warranty.WarrantyReport = ResolveService<WarrantyReportService>().Get(new WarrantyReport { WarrantyId = warranty.Id });
        }

        return warranty;
    }
```

I have changed `ConfigureDb` as per @mythz answer below:

```
    private static void ConfigureDb(Container container)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
    }
```

The service needs to call out other services to populate the other objects on my `Warranty` object, I'm not sure on how to improve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IDbConnectionFactory` like all connection managers is a thread-safe **factory** to create DB Connections, i.e. it's not a DB connection itself. It is supposed to be registered as a singleton.

By default ServiceStack's IOC (Funq) registers as a Singleton by default, so the correct registration is just:

```cs
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```

#### Resolving Services

As ServiceStack Services have the potential to utilize managed resources, they should be used within a using statement whenever they're resolved from another service, so that they're appropriately disposed of, e.g:

```cs
using var orders = ResolveService<WarrantyOrderService>();
using var status = ResolveService<WarrantyStatusService>();

var warranty = new Warranty { 
    WarrantyOrder = orders.Get(new WarrantyOrder { WarrantyId = warranty.Id }),
    WarrantyStatus = status.Get(new WarrantyStatus { 
        WarrantyId = warranty.StatusId }),
   //etc
}       

return warranty;
```

Comment: So, am I using `Db` incorrectly then or not setting it's `ReuseScope` correctly?

Comment: Yes remove the `ReuseScope` as Funq registers as a Singleton by default.

Comment: I'm finding the issue is still occurring, see the edit @mythz

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff that's because they need to be used in a using statement if the services makes use of disposable resources, see updated answer.

Comment: Does this mean that property-injected services are not disposed correctly or does the container take care of it? For example where WarrantyOrderService (from above) is an injected property of the outer service.

Comment: @jeffgabhart ServiceStack only disposes the Services, Filters, Dependencies, etc that it resolves itself. So if you manually resolve an autowired dependency from the IOC yourself (i.e. what [ResolveService does under-the-hood](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HostContext.cs#L299)) than you're responsible for disposing it.